# Not able to convert Canvas with chart and images using toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I have a bar chart (using chart.js) with labels as images and when i try to export the canvas to image it only exports the chart part not the images(labels), but the same canvas when I right click and save as image is able to exporting correctly (both the chart and label images).

Can someone help me with this issue.

my js file:

```
var config = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [ "20", "10", "2", "5", "1", "22" ],
        backgroundColor: [ '#f1f33a', '#99d695', "#cc8e50", '#ec9089', '#8e7bd4', '#eef5ce' ]   
      }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 1,
      onComplete: function(charttt) {
        var chartInstance = charttt.chart,
        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

        ctx.textAlign = 'right';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/yDYW1I7.png';
                var data = dataset.data[index];

                ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x - 20, bar._model.y - 10);
                img.onload = function() {
                  ctx.drawImage(img, bar._model.x, bar._model.y, 10, 10);
                }
            });
        });
        var url = document.getElementById('barChart').toDataURL('image/png');
        document.getElementById("testimg").src = url;
        }
    },
    legend: {
      "display": false
    },
    responsive:false,
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
var chartt = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm thinking you're problem is here...

```
    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
```

you're trying to get the meta of dataset `i`
but `i` is not defined

need to add the argument to the `forEach` function

```
    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {  // <-- here
        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var config = {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [ "20", "10", "2", "5", "1", "22" ],
          backgroundColor: [ '#f1f33a', '#99d695', "#cc8e50", '#ec9089', '#8e7bd4', '#eef5ce' ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 1,
        onComplete: function(charttt) {
          var chartInstance = charttt.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

          ctx.textAlign = 'right';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

          this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
              var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
              meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                  var img = new Image();
                  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/yDYW1I7.png';
                  var data = dataset.data[index];

                  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                  ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x - 20, bar._model.y - 10);
                  img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img, bar._model.x, bar._model.y, 10, 10);
                  }
              });
          });
          var url = document.getElementById('barChart').toDataURL('image/png');
          document.getElementById("testimg").src = url;
          }
      },
      legend: {
        "display": false
      },
      responsive:false,
      chartArea: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    }
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
  var chartt = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
<img id="testimg"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

there are two issues causing the images not to appear in the export.

first, adding images from another domain taints the canvas.
afterwards, a security error will prevent the canvas from being exported.
a work around is to add the `crossorigin` attribute to the image being added to the chart.

```
img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
```

next, before exporting the chart,
we have to wait for all of the images to load,
in the `img.onload` event.

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var config = {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [ "20", "10", "2", "5", "1", "22" ],
          backgroundColor: [ '#f1f33a', '#99d695', "#cc8e50", '#ec9089', '#8e7bd4', '#eef5ce' ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 1,
        onComplete: function(charttt) {
          var chartInstance = charttt.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

          ctx.textAlign = 'right';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

          var countDatasets = this.data.datasets.length;
          this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
              var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
              var countMeta = meta.data.length;
              meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                  var img = new Image();
                  img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
                  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/yDYW1I7.png';
                  var data = dataset.data[index];

                  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                  ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x - 20, bar._model.y - 10);
                  img.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img, bar._model.x, bar._model.y, 10, 10);
                    countMeta--;
                    if (countMeta === 0) {
                      countDatasets--;
                    }
                    if ((countDatasets === 0) && (countMeta === 0)) {
                      var url = document.getElementById('barChart').toDataURL('image/png');
                      document.getElementById("testimg").src = url;
                    }
                  }
              });
          });
        }
      },
      legend: {
        "display": false
      },
      responsive:false,
      chartArea: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    }
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
  var chartt = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
<img id="testimg"/>
```

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, while copying the code to stackoverflow i missed the variable 'I'. the variable is defined in the forEach call in my code. if you check the generated image in the above snippet it is not showing sun while it shows the same in the canvas. that is my problem.

Comment: you sir are a genius & thanks !! one small doubt though, what made you think to add counters ? (this could help in my future debugging)

Comment: because the image onload function is async, we're not sure when it is going to finish. so we use counters to ensure all the data sets, meta. and images are finished loading...